# expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘for’

Tags: c

```
/** @file alloc.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


#define NEW_BLOCK_SIZE 1024 
#define ARRAY_SIZE 31


typedef struct _metadata_mem
{
size_t size;
void * addr ;
struct _metadata_mem * next_free ;
struct _metadata_mem * pre_free;
char * unit ; 


} metadata_mem;

#define SIZE_OF_MATEDATA sizeof(metadata_mem) 



metadata_mem * array_of_block[31] ; 

int i;
for(i=0; i<31; i++){
    array_of_block[i]=NULL; 
}


int index(size_t size){
int count=0;
while((int)size>=2){
    size/=2;
    count++;
}
return count ; 

}
```

I received the following error and it starts in the for loop:

```
gcc alloc.c -O3 -Wextra -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -o    alloc.so -shared -fPIC
alloc.c:30:2: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘for’
alloc.c:30:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘<’ token
alloc.c:30:26: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘++’ token
alloc.c:35:5: error: conflicting types for ‘index’
make: *** [alloc.so] Error 1
```

I have no idea what's wrong with the for loop. It seems OK. Am I not supposed to initialized the array_of_block in the global context ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is the main() function?

Comment: C is not a scripting language.

Comment: Also, there's an easier way to do what you want with that array using `memset`.

Comment: Typo: SIZE_OF_MATEDATA :)

Comment: NULL is not guaranteed to be the same as 0x0 in memory, so technically memset() is a mistake for writing NULL pointers.  In practice it usually works because NULL usually really is 0x0 in memory.

Comment: But how do I initialize these pointers to NULL ? This is the beginning of a re-implementation of malloc() function and I'm trying to use this array of metadata_mem pointers to store the address of the memory blocks that are freed. I need to initialize it in the global context because it only needs to be initialized once and I can use it in other functions.

Comment: To initialize all the members to null pointer: `metadata_mem * array_of_block[31] = {};`

Answer (score 11):

The code needs to be inside a function.  If this code is the only code in the program, the function is called "main".  In its (almost) simplest form:

```
int main() {
    ... your code
}
```

Comment: The full definition not only returns int, but also takes argc/argv/env.  I was going for simplicity...

Comment: the problem is I need to initialize this array of metadata_mem in the global context so that I can access it in the following functions (which I didn't put here). What are other ways to initialize all of its entries to null in the global context ?

Comment: The return value of `main` should always be `int`, otherwise it's undefined behavior. I saw you have updated it, +1 now.

Comment: Probably most straightforwardly: `metadata_mem * array_of_block[31] = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL }`

Comment: @YuHao How about embedded programs, where you never want to return from main?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while, but that "for" statement needs to be wrapped in a function, doesn't it?  Don't think you can do procedural statements at the file block level.